# How can I know what should be a comment or a separate answer?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to make sense out of pending reviews of a suggested edit. I am trying to learn from this experience but need some help with understanding what I am missing.  It might be a case of me not understanding a particular rule or guideline, whether not it is explicitly stated in the help sections.

I have no dispute with the reasons for edit rejection. I am puzzled, however, as to why these are their views. According to the reviewers, my suggested edit:

- "deviates from the original intent of the post"
- "makes no sense as an edit"
- "should have been written as a comment or an answer"

As the person who asked the question in the first place, the suggested edit certainly made sense to me. In paraphrase: (a) [original content] no there is no current solution to the problem, and (b) [my contribution] if you absolutely must have X, then this is your workaround. If I were looking for the answer to the question, I would be helped because I would know the answer and what I could do next. In the workplace, I have had it hammered into me: if no is the answer, then *always* present other options.

I also edited the "answer" because I wanted to also acknowledge the contribution of the person who helped me reach that answer. Wouldn't it be [insert bad word here] if I made my own answer and marked that as the right one?

Am I really missing something obvious about the rules and guidelines, or does this appear to merely be a difference of opinion? I am raising this question and details because I really am trying to improve my interaction with Stack Overflow but find some matters to be non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do in that case is ask the user to edit it into their answer, and if they wont, make your own answer and accept it. It's not your fault they didn't take the time to take credit for it, and you're helping the community by making the answer visible. Don't forget to attribute anything from their answers or comments properly.

Comment: That's helpful, but what about the concept of adding an alternative when the answer is "no"?  If I read the reviewer comments in a literal fashion, they would consider that off-topic or ill-fitting. Is my attempt to add an alternative considered a no-no?

Comment: Reveiwers don't always choose the best reasoning, don't take them too literally.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge Don't add an alternative to someone else's answer, that is putting words in their mouth and can negatively affect the score of the answer. Even if the alternative came from them in a comment, they may not be confident enough in that solution to put it in A place where it can affect their rep.

Comment: It sounds like a game where "points matter." In any case, it looks like adding my own answer sounds like the best course of action.